# Compare a varying number of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, compare

I'm writing a script that I'm going to use quite often, with datasets of different sizes, and I have to do some comparisons that I just can't get straight in Python.

There will be multiple lists (around 20 or more, but I've reduced them to three for example and testing purposes), all with the same number of integer items in a certain order. I want to compare items on the same position in every list to find differences.
For a defined number of lists, this is easy:

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
c = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for x,y,z in zip(a,b,c):
    if x != y != z:
        print x, y, z
```

*I've tried wrapping that loop in a function, so the number of arguments can vary, but there I got stuck.*

```
def compare(*args):
    for x in zip(args):
        ???
```

In the final script I will have not multiple single lists, but all together in one list of list. Would that help? If I loop through a list of lists, I won't get every list at once...

**Forget the function**, it's not really useful anyway as it will be part of a bigger script and it's too difficult defining the different arguments.
I'm now comparing two lists at a time, saving those that are identical. That way, I can later easily remove all those from my whole list and keep only the unique ones.

```
l_o_l = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

for i in range(0, (len(l_o_l)-1)):
    for j in range((i+1), len(l_o_l)):
        if l_o_l[i] == l_o_l[j]:
            duplicates.append(key_list[i])
            duplicates.append(key_list[j])
dup = list(set(duplicates))
uniques = [x for x in key_list if x not in dup]
```

where the key_list contains, from a dictionary, identifiers for my lists.

Any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: how about unpacking the tuple to a list? `for x in zip(args): lst = list(x)` and then `if len(set(lst)) != 1: print lst`.

Comment: What is the meaning of `l_o_l`? Just curious `:P`

Comment: @OscarMederos `list_of_lists`. ;-) I know it's a bit misleading, but I couldn't think of anything better.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this

```
def compare(*args):
    for things in zip(*args):
        yield all(x == things[0] for x in things)
```

You can then use it like this

```
a = range(10)
b = range(10)
c = range(10)
d = range(11, 20)

for match in compare(a,b,c):
    print match

for match in compare(a,b,c,d):
    print match
```

Here is a demo using your example (its a generator, so you have to iter over it or exhaust it using `list`)

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
b = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
c = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

print list(compare(a,b,c))
```

Comment: This only prints "True" for my example, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Ah, go it. Thanks for the additional example! In my case, it would be enough to know if the lists are different, though. The results of the comparison of all values are only of minor interest.

Answer (score 1):

```
def compare(*args):
    for x in zip(args):
        values_list = list(x[0]) # x[0] because x is a tuple
        different_values = set(values_list) # a set does not contain identical values
        if len(different_values) != 1: # if you have more than 1 value you have different values in your list
            print 'different values', values_list
```

gives you

```
a = [0, 0, 1]
b = [0, 1, 1]
c = [1, 1, 1]
compare(a, b, c)
>>> different values [0, 0, 1]
>>> different values [0, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def compare(elements):
    return len(set(elements)) == bool(elements)
```

If you want to know whether all the lists are the same you can simply do:

```
all(compare(elements) for elements in zip(the_lists))
```

An alternative could be to transform the `list`s into `tuple`s and use `set` there:

```
len(set(tuple(the_list) for the_list in the_lists) == bool(the_lists)
```

If you simply want to remove duplicates this should be faster:

```
the_lists = [list(elem) for elem in set(tuple(the_list) for the_list in the_lists)]
```

Example usage:

```
>>> a = range(100)
>>> b = range(100, 200)
>>> c = range(200, 300)
>>> d = a[:]
>>> e = b[:]
>>> the_lists = [a,b,c,d,e]
>>> the_lists2 = [list(elem) for elem in set(tuple(the_list) for the_list in the_lists)]
>>> [a,b,c] == sorted(the_lists2)  #order is not maintained by set
True
```

It seems to be pretty fast:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('[list(elem) for elem in set(tuple(the_list) for the_list in the_lists)]', 'from __main__ import the_lists', number=1000000)
7.949447154998779
```

Less than 8 seconds for executing 1 million times. (Where `the_lists` is the same used before.)

**Edit:**
If you want to remove only the duplicated `list` then the simplest algorithm I can think of is sorting the list-of-lists and using `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> a = range(100)
>>> b = range(100,200)
>>> c = range(200,300)
>>> d = a[:]
>>> e = b[:]
>>> the_lists = [a,b,c,d,e]
>>> the_lists.sort()
>>> import itertools as it
>>> for key, group in it.groupby(the_lists):
...     if len(list(group)) == 1:
...             print key
... 
[200, 201, 202, ..., 297, 298, 299]
```

Comment: No, I don't want to remove duplicates, I want to find unique lists (or you could probably call it patterns) in a collection of lists. You have a lot of good ideas, though.

Comment: @Lilith-Elina I've updated my answer. By the way, solutions *based on comparisons* are Ω(nlogn), because the problem is "equivalent" to the problem of finding if a sequence contains two equal elements which is "equivalent" to sorting. If you want a faster solution then you must come up with something that does not compare the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the lists are similar to the ones in the example, I would use:

```
def compare(*args):
    for x in zip(args):
        if min(x) != max(x):
             print x
```

Answer (score -1):

I think trying to get clever with *args and zip is just confusing the issue.  I would write it something like this:

```
def compare(list_of_lists):
    # assuming not an empty data set
    inner_len = len(list_of_lists[0])
    for index in range(inner_len):
        expected = list_of_lists[0][index]
        for inner_list in list_of_lists:
            if inner_list[index] != expected:
                # report difference at this index
```

Comment: Why are you iterating over `range(inner_len)`? You could simply do `for expected in list_of_lists[0]:`. Iterating over indexes is not idiomatic and is usually a lot slower than normal iteration.

Comment: No, that's not quite right, because we need the index to consult the right element in the other lists. It could be changed to use something like `for index, expected in enumerate(list_of_lists[0]):`, but I personally find the way I wrote it above to be more readable.

Comment: And that's why `enumerate` exists.